# I want to show my flutter app in open with option when any user tap on the shared location over whatsapp

Tags: flutter

What I want to do is
Use Case - let suppose I have shared my current location with anyone on whatsapp or some share their current location on whats app with. So when I tap on that location it shows me few apps to open with Google Maps, Uber, Ola, Rapido (As i have installed these app and I am in India)

But we have created a taxi app like Uber and ola so I also want to show my app in open with. Please help me to achieve this in flutter.

Below is the screenshot I want to achieve

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWpFj.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`receive_sharing_intent`](https://pub.dev/packages/receive_sharing_intent) package, and look for `map.google.com` urls